# When pulling images from a Firebase storage the images don’t load until I interact with the tableView by scrolling... SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, swift

I’m running into problems with a twitter/instagram like news feed…

When pulling images from a Firebase storage the images don’t load until I interact with the tableView by scrolling... the more I scroll, the more I can get to appear. It also sometimes randomly displays the wrong post image until I scroll some more and eventually all images load and they all settle in their correct places.

It doesn’t make sense… all my logic is correct and I am using cachedImages when loading the image urls from the database. I’ve watched a lot video tutorials and they all use similar approaches as I’ve used but none of them have any buggy problems ike I do.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

CODE:

```html
var imageCache = [String: UIImage]()

var lastURLUsedToLoadImage: String?
```

```html
// loading user image  from urls
extension UIImageView {
    
    func loadImage(urlString: String) {
        
        lastURLUsedToLoadImage = urlString
        
        if let cachedImage = imageCache[urlString] {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to fetch post image:", err)
                return
            }
            
            if url.absoluteString != lastURLUsedToLoadImage {
                return
            }
            
            guard let imageData = data else { return }
            
            let photoImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            
            imageCache[url.absoluteString] = photoImage
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = photoImage
            }
            
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I tucked everything in a Custom UIImageView Class except for the var imageCache = String: UIImage. I left that global. Everything is working fine.

So rather than the UIImageView being an extension, it is its own custom class.

So change all UIImageView's using the loadImage(urlString: String) function to a CustomImageView.

Example:

@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!

change to

@IBOutlet weak var userImage: CustomImageView!

```
import UIKit

// global var
var imageCache = [String: UIImage]()

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

    var lastURLUsedToLoadImage: String?

    func loadImage(urlString: String) {
        lastURLUsedToLoadImage = urlString

        self.image = nil

        if let cachedImage = imageCache[urlString] {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to fetch post image:", err)
                return
            }

            if url.absoluteString != self.lastURLUsedToLoadImage {
                return
            }

            guard let imageData = data else { return }

            let photoImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

            imageCache[url.absoluteString] = photoImage

            // update the UI
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = photoImage
            }

            }.resume()
    }
}
```

Example of calling the load method:

```
cell.userImage.loadImage(urlString: userImageUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

when image downloaded.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would get the extension to recognize the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your variable lastURLUsedToLoadImage is global - you must store that data "per cell", not globally.

This is not easy task, I recommend to use image-caching library, like this one https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Loading images using Kingfisher is pretty easy, look at this:

```
imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: urlString))
```

Comment: I figured it out. You were on the right track earlier when asking if the var lastURLUsedToLoadImage: String? was a global variable... it was and that is incorrect. I tucked the everything in an in a CustomImageView Class except for the var imageCache = [String: UIImage]()... I left that global... Everything is working fine.